# Better nice: how can I pause a demanding process completely if the computer is unidle?

Tags: command-line, performance, process, idle, nice

Some background jobs on my PC do heavy processing. Running them with maximum nice level still produces slow interactivity and annoys me.

Is there a better way than maximum nice?

As soon as I use the PC I want the background job to stop. It can continue if I don't use the PC for about five minutes.

The background job has no dead line. If it does not matter if it takes much longer.

The job I want to slow down is a video encoding process which uses one thread per CPU. On my laptop there are 4 threads producing 400% load.

Comment: Do you know what background jobs you want removed?

Comment: @DevRobot I want a video encoding process to be as nice as possible. I don't want it to be removed. I added info about the job in the question.

Comment: You want it terminated though?

Comment: @DevRobot no, I don't want it to terminate. I want to stop and continue the job. I found this: `kill -SIGSTOP [pid]`,  `kill -SIGCONT [pid]` AFAIK the unix process model has all that is needed for this. The process (and the source code for it) needs no changes.

Comment: @JacobVlijm yes, I read your answer and upvoted it. The sparetime between xmas und new year is gone. Workdays are ahead. This question is my personal stuff. I will accept the answer after trying it. The script looks good. I will try it sooner or later. OK?

Comment: How are you launching your background work, and are you sure `nice` is actually being `nice`? I ask because how `nice` works changed a few years ago, such that it can have no effect, depending on groupings (I didn't describe it well, because I forget the details). You could test via launching with a known nice shell and/or disabling autogroups (`/proc/sys/kernel/sched_autogroup_enabled`). Note: I think disabling autogroups is NOT retroactive to things, and shells, that are already running.

Comment: @DougSmythies I start the background job via a unity-launcher.  When the job slows down the interactivty, I get annoyed and then I run `top` and renice the job. But this does not help much. It is a single process which does not start child-processes. If I run `top` some minutes later the nice level is still visible. I think that `nice` does work like it should. I guess it is more the IO-part than the CPU-part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### An alternative way to manage (pause) a demanding process while the computer is used

I tested the script below in combination with `kdenlive`, rendering a large video. In the tests, it worked fine. The (background) script itself consumes practically no resources. The only thing it basically does is check once per 5 seconds if the targeted process runs. Only if so, it will check the current idle time. Both mean *nothing* to your system

The script is based on the usage of `xprintidle`.  `xprintidle` keeps track of both keyboard- and mouse events and measures the time there was no activity. If the demanding process starts, it is immediately paused (since the computer is obviously used) with the command:

```
kill -STOP <pid>
```

If, subsequently, the idle time exceeds a certain (arbitrary) time limit, the process is resumed, using the command:

```
kill -CONT <pid>
```

Subsequently, if idle time returns to below the set time limit, the process is paused again and so on.

[image]

*cpu usage before/during/after idle time, rendering a large video with kdenlive using melt*

#### About kill -STOP and kill -CONT

Although the arguments `-STOP` and `-CONT` are mentioned in `man kill`, it is not explained, strangely. However, for example [here](http://www.pervasivecode.com/blog/2010/04/03/unix-tip-kill-stop-and-kill-cont/comment-page-1/) we can read what it does:

*Basically `kill -STOP 1234` will pause the process with `pid 1234`, and `kill -CONT 1234` will resume it. It’s as if you can sleep individual applications instead of your entire computer.*

Thus the demanding process is put to sleep while the computer is used (un- idle).

#### Finding the process to be paused

The script runs with the process *name* (you'd like to be paused if you use the computer) as an argument.

The trick is to find the correct process to be paused. It won't be the name of your video editor, since it will certainly use external tools to render. In my case, `kdenlive` used `melt`. The script successfully paused `melt` and resumed rendering after a defined idle time.

You can use the `top` command if you are unsure about the process name. Run `top` in a terminal and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to sort on memory usage. The demanding process will be in the top.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys

limit = int(sys.argv[1])
proc = sys.argv[2]

def get(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command).decode("utf-8").strip()

def check_runs(proc):
    try:
        return get(["pgrep", proc])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

pid1 = check_runs(proc)
t1 = int(int(get("xprintidle"))/1000)

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    pid2 = check_runs(proc)
    # (only) if the process exists, manage its activity
    if pid2 != None:
        t2 = int(int(get("xprintidle"))/1000)
        # if the process just started, obviously the system is not idle ->
        # pause the process (try in case it was killed by user in between):
        if pid1 == None:
            try:
                subprocess.Popen(["kill", "-STOP", pid2])
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                pass
        # If there is a change in time status (breaktime entered or ended)
        else:              
            if [t2 > limit, t1 > limit].count(True) == 1:
                if t2 > limit:
                    cmd = ["kill", "-CONT", pid2]
                else:
                    cmd = ["kill", "-STOP", pid2]
                subprocess.Popen(cmd)
        t1 = t2
    pid1 = pid2
```

#### How to use

- The script needs `xprintidle`

  ```
  sudo apt-get instal xprintidle
  ```
- Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `manage_proc.py`
- Test- run it by the command

  ```
  python3 /path/to/manage_proc.py <seconds> <process_name>
  ```

  where `<seconds>` is the idle time in seconds before you'd like your process to start. 
  Startup the consuming process *after* the script started.
- If all works fine, add the script to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add the command:

  ```
   python3 /path/to/manage_proc.py <seconds> <process_name>
  ```

Comment: This answer looks good. But maybe there is an easier solution. I will start a bounty.